# "No version for 'optional' dependency..." when updating Solaris 11.3

Tags: updates, solaris

I'm having trouble updating Solaris 11.3. The problems below show up on both a DL360 G5 hardware (dual Xeons), and a VM guest (Core i7). The Solaris installations use Sun's image, and I did not perform any customization other than to [enable their Software Repository for Sun Studio](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37072/gozsz.html).

I found [Adding and Updating Software in Oracle Solaris 11.3](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54739/constraints.html), but I have to admit I'm too inexperienced to use it to solve a problem that's not listed. Searching for some of the error messages is not producing anything useful.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

---

```
$ sudo pkg update
Creating Plan (Running solver): /
pkg update: No solution was found to satisfy constraints
No solution found to update to latest available versions.
This may indicate an overly constrained set of packages are installed.

latest incorporations:

  pkg://solaris/consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.9.0.2.0:20160528T012705Z

The following indicates why the system cannot update to the latest version:

    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/ncurses@5.7-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/ncurses@5.7-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-imaging-27@1.1.7-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/popt@1.16-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-imaging-27@1.1.7-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-imaging@1.1.7-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version matching 'conditional' dependency library/python/python-imaging-27@1.1.7,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.90.0 can be installed
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/file/gnu-findutils@4.6.0-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/file/gnu-findutils@4.5.14-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/popt@1.7-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.12.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-imaging@1.1.7-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version matching 'conditional' dependency library/python/python-imaging-27@1.1.7,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.95.0 can be installed
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-zope-interface-27@3.3.0-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-twisted-27@10.1.0-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-zope-interface-27@3.3.0-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
    Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency library/python/python-zope-interface@3.3.0,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.95.0 can be installed
      ----------------------------------------
      Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-zope-interface@3.3.0-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
      Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
      ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-zope-interface@3.3.0-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  [already rejected; see above]
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-twisted@10.1.0-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
    Reason:  No version matching 'conditional' dependency library/python/python-twisted-27@10.1.0,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.95.0 can be installed
      ----------------------------------------
      Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-twisted-27@10.1.0-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
      Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
      ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-twisted-27@10.1.0-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  [already rejected; see above]
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-zope-interface@3.3.0-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/library/python/python-twisted@10.1.0-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version for 'optional' dependency on consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@5.12,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.14.0 can be found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the Oracle docs on [Installing Sun Studio](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37072/gozsz.html) missed a step.

To ensure the packages could update, this command needed to be run, which was found under [Updating a Package Constrained by an Incorporation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54739/constraints.html):

```
pkg change-facet facet.version-lock.consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation=false
```

---

Once the change was made, things completed as expected:

```
$ sudo ~/do-update.sh 
            Packages to update:   7
       Create boot environment:  No
Create backup boot environment: Yes

DOWNLOAD                                PKGS         FILES    XFER (MB)   SPEED
Completed                                7/7         69/69      3.8/3.8  1.5M/s

PHASE                                          ITEMS
Removing old actions                           29/29
Installing new actions                         39/39
Updating modified actions                      52/52
Updating package state database                 Done 
Updating package cache                           7/7 
Updating image state                            Done 
Creating fast lookup database                   Done 
Updating package cache                           2/2 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: Please review release notes posted at:

http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=solaris11&id=SERNS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**EDIT:** it was reported the solution works for SPARC based Solaris 11.3 as well as Intel hardware. Also see [“No version for 'optional' dependency…” when updating Solaris 11.3 on SPARC hardware](https://superuser.com/q/1144178).

Comment: I can confirm this works on Solaris 11.3 on non-Oracle X86_64 hardware (Supermicro server)

Answer (score 0):

I had to run sudo pkg update --accept, all worked with that accept flag.  Running Solaris 11.3 in a Parallels VM environment on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link how to solve these problems:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54739/constraints.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.